# Doubt in a problem of special theory of relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

I am studying A.P. French's Special Relativity and there a problem is given

> As the text points out, an observer does not have a complete view of what is happening everywhere in his reference frame at a given instant; he is aware only of what is happening at his location at that instant. Suppose a meter stick pointing in the x direction moves along the x-axis with a speed $0.8c$, with its midpoint passing through the origin at $t=0$. Assume the observer is situated at the point $x = 0m$ and $y = 1m$.
> a) Where in the observer's frame is the midpoint of the meter stick at $t=0$?
> b)When does the observer see the midpoint pass through the origin?
> c) Where do the endpoints appear to be at this time?

The problem is easy but I got stuck in the part (b).

Consider a frame $S$ in which the stick is moving relative to it by velocity $0.8c$ in $+x$ direction.
Take another frame $S'$ in which the stick appears to be at rest.
At $t=t='0$, $x=x'=0$, meaning the midpoint of rod in both the frames is agt the origin or more precisely the origin of the both the frame touches each other at $t=0$.
As the rod is at rest in the frame $S'$, the coordinates of the left and tright end of rod is $x'_1=-0.5$ and $x'_2=+0.5$.
As in $S$ we have an observer at (0,1), so all the clocks in the $S$ frame is synchronised and $t_1=t_2=0$.

So, we have the following information,
$$x'_1=-1/2, x'_2=+1/2, t'_1=?, t'_2=?$$
$$x_1=?, x_2=?, t_1=t_2=0$$
$$\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{0.64c^2}{c^2}}}=\frac{10}{6}$$

As $$x'_1=\gamma(x_1-vt_1)$$
$$\implies -\frac{1}{2}=\frac{10}{6}(x_1-0)$$
$$\boxed{
\implies x_1=-0.3  \\   
\text{Similarly}\;\; x_2=+0.3}$$
We can find $$t'_1=\gamma\Big(t_1-\frac{0.8cx_1}{c^2}\Big)=\frac{10}{6}\Big(0-\frac{(0.8)(-0.3)}{3\times10^8}\Big)$$
$$\boxed{
\implies t'_1=1.33\times10^{-9}s  \\   
\text{Similarly},\;\; t'_2=-1.33\times10^{-9}}$$

In **part (b)**,
The time at which the midpoint of rod passes through the origin =
$$\frac{\text{Length of rod in S frame}/2}{\text{Speed of rod}}=\frac{0.3}{0.8\times3\times10^{8}}=\frac{1}{8}\times10^{-8}=0.125\times10^{-8}s$$
But the answer to the part (b) is given as $0.33\times10^{-8} s$.
I am not able to understand where I am wrong in part (b)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not examined your answer in detail, but I suspect you have overcomplicated things.

You re told that at time t=0 the centre of the stick is at x = 0 y = 0. The observer is a meter away from that point, so the light takes an extra 3.3 nanoseconds to reach the observer.